# My site is not working properly in mobile, it's working fine in desktop version

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, responsive-design

Actually my site content working in opposite direction to background image. So I use j query to calculate height of every section and position my main section in negative top position. When I scroll my content with mouse wheel its goes top to bottom and background move bottom to top. But in mobile it's not working. I have assign height to every main section on run time according to content and window height which is greater then.

i am using my concept with 2 div. one for background and other for content. for this i calculate total height of content and move content div in negative but in mobile it doesn't work properly.

```
$("div.content_scroll").css({
            'top': -(totalHeight + topmaindiv - ($(window).height() - $("#main-nav").height())) + "px",
    });
```

when i scroll content in mobile it;s not moving down

any one can have solution for this

Comment: Do you have a demo site or jsfiddle available?

Comment: Please this link for demo: http://182.71.19.27/design/cavanough/index2.html